# How to retrive the tag value entered in dialog in aem in javascript?

Tags: javascript, aem

I need to get the value of the tag entered in dialog.

The sling:reosurcetype is cq/gui/components/coral/common/form/tagfield

I have tried using a graniteClass getting the value something like `$(".tagid")[0].value` where `tagid` is the graniteclass name but this doesn't seem to me working.

I need to get the data in this screenshot iin javascript in aem

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graniteclass worked

var tags = $this.find("[data-id='tagi'").find("input").val();
where tagi is the id name of the graniteclass